# Does not string.gmatch() return nil in Lua?

Tags: string, lua, null

```
local str = ",23,4"
local t = {}
local i = 1

for temp in str:gmatch("[^,]+") do
  t[i] = temp
  i = i + 1
end
```

I'm a Lua newbie. Here is my code. I expected that `t[1]` has `nil`. However, `gmatch()` skipped it instead of returning `nil`. Tabel `t[]` has only two key-values. If I make table `t[]` like this

```
t[1] = nil
t[2] = 23
t[3] = 4
```

, how do I use `gmatch()`? Or what function do I have to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gmatch()` didn't skip anything; it did exactly what you told it to: it found every occurrance of  `"[^,]+"`, of which there are two, and handed each of them to the loop body.

If you want to match empty strings as well, you can change your pattern to `"[^,]*"`.

`+` matches one or more

`*` matches zero or more

Please refer to https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1